# Where is the function glCreateShaderObjectARB()?

Tags: opengl, c++11

Where is the function glCreateShaderObjectARB()? 
I included following:

```
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl\wglext.h>
#include <gl\glext.h>
```

But I can't use `glCreateShaderObjectARB()` function!

Similary, I want to use:

```
glShaderSourceARB();
glAttachObjectARB();
glCompileShaderARB();
glLinkProgramARB();
```

and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of [`GL_ARB_shader_objects`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_objects.txt), and unless you have an OpenGL implementation that pre-dates 2.0 you should not use it. Use core GLSL instead, the function names are slightly different (*e.g.* `glCreateShaderObjectARB (...)` is `glCreateShader (...)`), but functionally they are the same.

Any tutorial you come across that uses the ARB extension should really be ignored as it is too old (10 years) to be considered relevant today.

Furthermore, unless you are on OS X, you are going to have to load this function using your platform's extension loading mechanism at ***run-time***, including a header is not going to solve your problem. I would suggest you use [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) to make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should activate this prototype with a define before the include:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL/glext.h>
```